# eslint error: 'Uint32Array' is not defined. no-undef

Tags: eslint, typed-arrays, eslintrc

When using `Uint32Array` with TypeScript and eslint, I to this error.

```
34:43 error 'Uint32Array' is not defined   no-undef
```

How do I fix this?

My eslintrc looks like this (YAML syntax used):

```
env:
  browser: true
  jasmine: true
  jest:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `"es6": true` to you .eslintrc file. This tells eslint to consume the `"builtin"` globals that the browser JS engine provides.

Comment: See also https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7633#issuecomment-262092225